# create Custom Stanza using XMPP in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xmpp, xmppframework

I have tried to  create custom packet using following code  but It gets changed when It goes to XMPP lifeCycle.

```
NSString * strUser = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"kXMPPmyJID"];

XMLWriter* xmlWriter = [[XMLWriter alloc]init];

[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"presence"];
[xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"from" value:strUser];
[xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"to" value:appDelegate.chatUser];
[xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"type" value:@"typing.."];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];

NSString* xml = [xmlWriter toString];

NSXMLElement *xmlElement = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:xml error:nil];
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceFromElement:xmlElement];
[appDelegate.xmppStream sendElement:presence];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the xmpp protocol (http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html)
They say the type attribute must have one of the values stated in the protocol. If you want to add custom attributes you should add it in a custom tag, but the receiving side would have to handle it properly.

Comment: actually I want to create Custom packet .. I dont want to add any custom attribute or tag..                                                                                                                                                                   <presence id="W8838" to=“abc@test.com" from=“xyz@test.com" type="Typing"></presence>

Comment: It adds <x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"><photo/></x> tag where as I send following   PRESENSE:::::::   <presence 
 id="W8nrr-23" 
 to="alpanpatel@drifth.com" 
 from="bhavupatel@drifth.com" 
 type="Typing">
</presence>

Comment: XMPPStream class does changing in that Element

Answer (score 0):

You should add a custom element to your stanza, not set it as an attribute on the presence:

```
[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"presence"];
[xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"from" value:strUser];
[xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"to" value:appDelegate.chatUser];
[xmlWriter writeStartElementWithNamespace:@"vikram" localName:@"typing"];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];
```

Which will create:

```
<presence id='...' from='...' to='...'><typing xmlns='vikram'/></presence>
```

Although using presence to send typing notifications is a bad idea. Why not use [XEP-0085](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html)?